# Laravel - vagrant - "No input file specified."

Tags: laravel, vagrant

The error of the laravel/vagant application showing only "No input file specified." is as I googled well famous and well documented, but only for specific cases.

Isn't there any log file or query system that would allow the developer to determine what the error is? My laravel logs are empty and as I tried all the solutions I found on google/stackoverflow, I would really like to have details of this error instead of acting and trying things blindly.

Comment: Looks like this error is all you going to get.. Try setting up with composer https://www.culttt.com/2013/06/17/setting-up-vagrant-with-laravel-4/

Answer (score 0):

This is a webserver error not a PHP/Laravel error and means that it cannot find the index.php/index.html at the location specified in vhost/server block configuration.

If you are using nginx as webserver make sure that `root` points to the correct path (ex: `root /var/www/project_name/public`) inside server block conf file.

If you are using Apache make sure that `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` are pointing to the correct path in your `VirtualHost` file.